# Zero padding zfill function bug?

Tags: python

I have noticed that `str.zfill(x)` can return a string which is smaller than `x characters. For example:

```
>>> "%.2x".zfill(8) % 255
'0000ff'
>>> "%.2x".zfill(8) % 256
'0000100'
```

How is this strange behavior explained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour is correct. `zfill(x)` itself always return a string that is at least as long as the original string and with at least `x` characters. **It's `%` that is shortening it** by replacing `%.2f` with a shorter string:

```
>>> "%.2x" % 255
'ff'
```

Since `ff` is shorter than `%.2x` you end up with less characters.

Keep in mind that `zfill` knows nothing about the formatting specifiers and thus:

```
>>> "%.2x".zfill(8)
'0000%.2x'
```

as you can see the `%.2x` remains untouched and the later call to `%` replaces it with just `ff` shortening the string.

You have to call `zfill` *afterwards*:

```
>>> ("%.2x" % 255).zfill(8)
'000000ff'
```

---

Also note that you can avoid callinf `zfill` and doing everything with the string formatting:

```
>>> "%08.2x" % 255
'000000ff'
```

The `0` is the filling character and the `8` is the width of the string.

---

Side note: specifying both a total width of `8` and a precision of `2` is actually useless. The only effect of specifying `.2x` is to add a `0` in front of numbers less than `16`:

```
>>> "%.2x" % 5
'05'
>>> "%.2x" % 10
'0a'
```

It does not have any effect when the numbers are bigger:

```
>>> "%.2x" % 16
'10'
>>> "%x" % 16
'10'
```

And the `8` zero-fill would add that `0` anyway, so the format specifier `%08.2x` is exactly equivalent to just `%08x`.